# Login to BottomNav

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

The app I'm developing is going to start with a login, which will be two different screens. After successfully logging in, the user will be redirected to a screen that will have a bottom navigation.

What is the "proper" way of going about this?  Should I have two separate activities?  Or one activity that uses [conditional navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional)?  If the latter, how would I setup the NavGraph and/or other code so I don't show the bottom nav during the login process?

Edit:  I'm not looking for code (apart from what the NavGraph would look like).

Comment: Sounds like the work for fragments buddy :)

Comment: 2 activities can be LoginActivity then HomeActivity.
HomeActtivity can then host your fragments each corresponding to a tab in Bottom Navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you should use two activities, one is `login activity` and another is a `home activity`
and that `home activity` with `fragments`.
this is the best way if you want to overlay the whole screen while logging in. Also, it will not show the bottom nav, as that will be in the separate activity(`Login Activity`).

as far as I know